# Скастовать IList<T> в IReadOnlyList<T>

Tags: c#

Нужен экземпляр-обёртка IReadOnlyList. Но внезапно я не могу скастовать его с IList.
Это напрямую значит, что у меня **нет никакой возможности** создать ReadOnly-коллекцию, не имя экземпляра непосредственно List, не так ли?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Интерфейс используется для доступа к полям и свойствам класса. Интерфейс как объект создать невозможно, но можно к нему привести экземпляр класса, который его реализует.

```cs
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "привет" };
IReadOnlyList<T> readOnlyList = (IReadOnlyList<T>)list; // апкаст
Console.WriteLine(readOnlyList[0]); // привет
readOnlyList[0] = "мир"; // ошибка компиляции
readOnlyList.Add("мир"); // ошибка компиляции
```

> Это напрямую значит, что у меня нет никакой возможности создать ReadOnly-коллекцию, не имя экземпляра непосредственно List, не так ли?

Верно.

По поводу реализации полей и свойств:

```cs
private List<string> _list;

public IReadOnlyList<string> List
{
    get => _list;
}
```

В данном варианте сам список доступен для изменения только внутри текущего класса, а наружу отдается он в виде интерфейса, который позволяет его только читать.

Comment: Спасибо.
Как я понял, использовать интерфейсы заместо полей в классе очень плохая идея...
Либо же дублировать частные типы в приватные.
Может, есть какая-нибудь договорённость на этот счёт?

Comment: @VladisS обновил ответ

Comment: _"В данном варианте сам список доступен для изменения только внутри текущего класса"_ Строго говоря это не так, ведь код вызывающий свойство может попытаться привести результат к изменяемому типу (`... as IList<string>`) и, если результат приведения не _null_, чего-то натворить с внутренним листом.

Comment: @i-one строго говоря, приватные поля на самом деле не приватные. Ведь есть рефлексия.

Comment: Чтобы порушить состояние такого класса рефлексия не потребуется. Когда пишется класс не всегда ведь известно что за код будет его вызывать и _как_ он написан. Если нужно чтобы внутренний список не изменялся безопаснее вернуть копию, или read-only обёртку (`.AsReadOnly()`).

Comment: @aeopt, спасибо!
Конечно, именно такую инкапсуляцию я и использую.
Просто мне подумалось: а почему я должен в полях использовать List<T>, а не IList<T>?
И я нарвался на эту проблему.
Нужно ли делать конкретный класс, и зависит ли это от степени сокрытия?
P.s. я готов читать соответствующую литературу, просто не знаю какую.

Comment: "Строго говоря это не так, ведь код вызывающий свойство может попытаться привести результат к изменяемому типу"
Использование is и as, кастинг наугад разве не есть хромая рефлексия?

Comment: @VladisS без разницы по сути, как будут устроены приватные поля. Главное - целостность логики, доступной публично. Можете и IList использовать. `IList<string> list = new List<string>()`. Смысл в том, что создать придется все равно класс. Интерфейс не может быть сам по себе объектом.

Comment: @VladisS, в System.Linq или System.Collection.Generic такой "кастинг наугад" не редкость. Посмотрите, например, [код](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/AnyAll.cs) метода `Any`. Если вызывающему коду требуется добавить элемент в список полученный из свойства, почему он не может "в целях оптимизации" попробовать скаститься в IList и добавить в него?

Comment: @aeopt, вы бесконечно правы, спасибо. Что-то я не подумал, что они же приватные)

Comment: @i-one, насколько я знаю Linq, используется там корявая рефлексия из-за зависимости структур данных от скорости, которыу запрятаны под IEnumerable как под самый общий тип.
Что же касается этого случая, то при попытке изменить такой лист вылетит **исключение**, об этом писалось на msdn, readonly коллекции нарушают принцип подстановки Лисков, вот оттуда корни и растут.
Что же касается **чистой архитектуры** (я подразумевал её в этом вопросе), то тут такой проблемы не существует)
Но всё равно спасибо.

Comment: @VladisS, не понял про исключение. [Вот](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eOgitX), например, внешний метод рушит состояние класса.

Comment: @i-one, действительно, я был неправ, спасибо за ваш вклад!

Comment: Я ориенитировался на эту статью раньше [https://habr.com/ru/post/256605/].
Хорошую фразу нашёл позже: "Интерфейс, это то, что класс может, а не то, что не может".